# Foreach loop unable to find object

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, eval

I am trying to use foreach with the parallel backend to speed up computation (of cross validation of an {AUCRF} random forest for feature selection, if this does matter). In the process of doing so i need to get a subset of a vector. The name of the vector can change but is accessible as character vector. I used the eval(parse()) construct(good idea?) to get a subset of the vector.

Example:

```
library(parallel)
library(foreach)
library(stats)

#create cluster
clu <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(clu, cores = detectCores() - 1)

bar<-c("a","b","c","d")
rab<-c(2,3)
bar.name<-"bar"

#expected output in this example is a list containing ten times
bar[rab]
#or
eval(parse(text=paste(bar.name,"[rab]",sep="")))

foo<-foreach(m = 1:10, .packages = c("stats")) %dopar% {
  sink("foreach.txt")
      print(bar.name)
      print(parse(text=paste(bar.name,"[rab]",sep="")))
      print(eval(parse(text=paste(bar.name,"[rab]",sep=""))))
  foo.temp<-eval(parse(text=paste(bar.name,"[rab]",sep="")))
  return(foo.temp)
}
sink()
stopCluster(clu)
```

However i get the following error:

```
Error in { : task 1 failed - "Object 'bar' not found"
```

I thought that each worker is getting a copy of the workspace with all objects. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This sounds like a bad design. It's almost never necessary to use `eval(parse())`.

To get a variable, `get()` is somewhat safer, like `get(bar.name)[rab]`. But you're still running into an environment issue here. Since you don't have the variables `bar` or `rab` in the body of the `dopar`, they are not exported to the environment where `foreach` is running the code. You can fix that with an explicit assignment of the `.export` parameter of foreach to make sure those variables are exported. Here I change to use `get` and only have to explicitly export `bar` because `rab` is now include in the box of the function.

```
foo<-foreach(m = 1:10, .export=c("bar"), .packages = c("stats")) %dopar% {
  get(bar.name)[rab]
}
```

A better idea would be rather than specifying a variable name, specify an element of a named list. For example

```
baz <- list(bar=letters[1:4], bob=letters[5:7])
```

Then you could do

```
baz.name <- "bar"
rab <- c(2,4)

foo<-foreach(m = 1:10, .packages = c("stats")) %dopar% {
  baz[[baz.name]][rab]
}
```

And because dopar can see the variables `baz`, `baz.name`, and `rab` you don't have to export anything.

Comment: Thanks a lot for clarification of both the eval(parse()) and object export issues!