# 'object not found' - when running `get` function within R foreach dopar

Tags: r, object, parallel-processing, get, quantmod

I have a vector called `tKKrs`, which is a list of stock tickers. Text strings in this vector also represent names of `xts` objects. All of the objects are already available in the environment. So is the vector `tKKrs`

If I want to see the content of an object A (which is the first text string in vector `tKKrs`), I can either type `A` or `get(tKKrs[1])`

However if I run `get(tKKrs[i])` inside dopar foreach loop, I get error `object A not found`.

How to make function `get` work within foreach dopar?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [could not find function inside foreach loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765256/could-not-find-function-inside-foreach-loop)

Comment: I cannot find an object, not a function. I believe there is a difference between function and object. My object is called "A" which is just coincidentally the same name as the name of a function in the thread you posted. My problem is, that I cannot retrieve an object within foreach loop when using get function.

Comment: See the `.export` argument, **which is described in the help file** `?foreach`: *"**.export** character vector of variables to export. This can be useful when accessing a variable that isn't defined in the current environment. The default value in NULL."*

Comment: also see `.verbose` which is a _logical flag enabling verbose messages. This can be very useful for trouble shooting._

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreach loop unable to find object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200982/foreach-loop-unable-to-find-object)

Comment: @nrussel Thank you very much for recommending`.export` argument. This probably appears to have solved my problem.